# MYSQL gives same response '0 rows affected' in different situations

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

MYSQL update query give same response in different situations

***"0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0789 sec)"***

1) where clause is not matched

2) where clause is matched but the given value is same to the existing value

**ex:**
assume that `user_id` = '86' is not exist in the table

```
UPDATE `undergraduate` set `faculty` = 'Efac' WHERE `user_id` = '86'
```

assume that `user_id` = '86' is exist. But the value 'Efac' is already in there

```
UPDATE `undergraduate` set `faculty` = 'Efac' WHERE `user_id` = '86'
```

**Question is what is the better way to identify both conditions significantly ?**

I'm using :
MYSQL :

```
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
```

PHP : 5.5.9-1 (PDO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## MySQL Command Line

If you are using the MySQL command line tool the output given will let you differentiate the two scenarios.

If the entry doesn't exist:

```
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | faculty |
+---------------+---------+
| 80            | abc     |
+---------------+---------+

mysql> UPDATE `undergraduate` set `faculty` = 'Efac' WHERE `user_id` = '86';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If the entry does exist, but isn't updated:

```
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | faculty |
+---------------+---------+
| 80            | abc     |
| 86            | Efac    |
+---------------+---------+

mysql> UPDATE `undergraduate` set `faculty` = 'Efac' WHERE `user_id` = '86';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If the entry does exist, and is updated:

```
+---------------+---------+
| user_id       | faculty |
+---------------+---------+
| 80            | abc     |
| 86            | bcd     |
+---------------+---------+

mysql> UPDATE `undergraduate` set `faculty` = 'Efac' WHERE `user_id` = '86';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

## PHP - PDO

PDO unfortunately doesn't provide a mechanism to get both rows matched *and* rows changed for a query, but you can choose which one you want. The default is to return the number of rows changed, but the option can be specified on connection to return the number of rows match instead:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=host', 'username', 'password', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true
));
```

## PHP - MySQLi

The MySQLi functions can do the same as PDO in terms of choosing between matched and updated:

```
$db = mysqli_init();
$db->real_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database', '3306', null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS);
```

But you can also call the function `mysqli_info()` / `$db->info()` (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) and it will return a string with the matched / updated rows which you could then parse:

```
Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention I'm use PHP not command line tool, question was updated

Comment: @Tech-Sira I've updated my answer with details on how to get this info in PHP.

Comment: Thank you this is what I expected answer !

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the C MySQL API (or a wrapper of that). From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed. The
> mysql_info() C API function returns the number of rows that were
> matched and updated and the number of warnings that occurred during
> the UPDATE.

And clicking on mysql_info [revealed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-info.html):

> **UPDATE**
>
> String format: *Rows matched: 40 Changed: 40 Warnings: 0*

That looks like something you can parse :)

**EDIT** BK435 said it wasn't clear whether I answered OP's question. I think I did: you can't get that info from the returned affected rows alone (obvious, since `0==0`, but you need to use `mysql_info`.

Comment: @BK435: I think I clearly answered that; but since you asked for it: update to my answer :)

Comment: instead of doing this i can simply run select query with the same where  clause and get affected row count but I thought there may be a better way than running two queries. I am looking for a simplest way.. but may be I'm wrong

Comment: What I proposed is the simplest way, according to the **official documentation**.